# How to read and set blobs index tags in azure function (c#)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have setup an azure function which has a blob storage trigger. I need to attach index tags to the blob when it is added...

Azure function:

```
public async static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

functions.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "path1/path2/{name}",
      "connection": "blob_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the ideal and simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
BlobUploadOptions options = new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        Tags = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "name", "myBlob" },
            { "type", "blobTrigger" },
            { "direction", "in" },
            { "path", "path1/path2/name" },
            { "connection", "blob_STORAGE" }
        }
    };

_ = await blobClient.UploadAsync(sampleFile.Path, options);
```

Or something like this:

```
BlobUploadOptions options = new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        Tags = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(yourJsonBindingsHere)
    };

_ = await blobClient.UploadAsync(sampleFile.Path, options);
```

[BlobUploadOptions.Tags Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions.tags?view=azure-dotnet)

[BlobClient.UploadAsync Method Overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#overloads)

The '{' and '}' characters are not valid for index names, if you meant those literally.

> - Tag keys and values must adhere to the following naming rules:
>
>   - Alphanumeric characters:
>
>     - a through z (lowercase letters)
>     - A through Z (uppercase letters)
>     - 0 through 9 (numbers)
>   - Valid special characters: space, plus, minus, period, colon, equals, underscore, forward slash ( +-.:=_/)

[Setting blob index tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#setting-blob-index-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following parameter types for the triggering blob:
Stream
TextReader
string
Byte[]
ICloudBlob
CloudBlockBlob
CloudPageBlob
CloudAppendBlob

Please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp). You will find all the possible approach here.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage version 5 and higher you can use new classes (BlockBlobClient, PageBlobClient, AppendBlobClient) as myBlob parameter type and the rest of the code will easily follow the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=net#upload-a-new-blob-with-index-tags